# I have an IMG and IFRAME and would like for them to display side by side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

This is what i have, not sure why its not showing side by side. I've tried using float left, and tried using the bootstrap grid with no success. Thank you.

```
<div class="container">
     <img src="placeholder" alt="picture of the band " width="500" height="300">
</div>
<div class="container">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/placeholder" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use  this . It works.

```
    .container{
        float: left;
    }
```

If you are using bootstrap replace `container` with any other class name and do `float:left` it works.

```
<style>
        .classname{
            float: left;
        }
</style>

<div class="classname">
     <img src="placeholder" alt="picture of the band " width="500" height="300">
</div>
<div class="classname">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/placeholder" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```